# Select a country name from the first drop-down and display the country phone code in the second drop-down with all the country code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using semantic UI. I have two dropdown list. First is the country name and second is country phone code.  I am able to display the country name and country code from the database when page load.

Now I am selecting the country name from the first drop-down so according to the country name I have to display the country code in the second list also I need all the country phone code in the second drop-down.

I tried AJAX to do this but using AJAX I am getting the right country phone code but it is not displaying the dropdown list.

For example:
If I choose the country name "United States" and in the second drop-down country phone code will display "1". Also, I need rest of all the phone code in the dropdown list.

In the page load, I am getting the country name and country phone code in the drop-down.

[image]
[image]

I choose the country name "Afghanistan" and I got country phone code is 93 which is correct but this time contact number dropdown not working. How do I reselect my phone code again?

[image]

Would you help me out in this?
**First dropdown**

```
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown" id="select_country">
      <input type="hidden" name="country">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
      <div class="menu">
      <?php
      $sql_country_list="SELECT `id`, `sortname`, `country_name`, `phonecode` FROM `countries`";
             if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_country_list)) {
              $stmt->execute();
              $stmt->store_result();
          $stmt->bind_result($id,$sortname,$country_name,$phonecode);
          while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                ?>
      <div class="item" data-value="<?php echo $sortname;?>"><i class="<?php echo $sortname;?> flag"></i><?php echo $country_name;?></div>
      <?php }}?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Second dropdown list**

```
<select class="ui search dropdown p_code" id="mobile_country_code" name="mobile_country_code">
  <?php
    $sql_country_no="SELECT `phonecode` FROM `countries`";
         if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_country_no)) {
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($phonecode);
         while ($stmt->fetch()){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $phonecode;?>"><?php echo $phonecode;?></option>
   <?php }}?>
    </select>
```

**AJAX call**

```
$('#select_country').dropdown({
 onChange: function(val) {
$.ajax({
    url:"process.php?key=country_mobilecode",
    method:"POST",
    data:'country_id='+val,
    success:function(data){
     $('.p_code').html(data);
     //alert(data);
    }
   });
 }
});
```

**Process.php**

```
$country_sc=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['country_id']));
  $state_data="SELECT phonecode FROM `countries` WHERE sortname=?";
  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($state_data)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $country_sc);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($phonecode);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $states="<option value=".$phonecode.">".$phonecode."</option>";
    echo $states;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: any console error?

Comment: @Wils, No there is no error. when I select the country name then it's called the ajax and display the country code but it's hiding my dropdown because I am getting the single value form AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

In your process.php you are creating list box items ie country mobile codes. You need just print that response which you get as the output of ajax call (if you create html content as a response)

```
<select class="ui search dropdown p_code" id="mobile_country_code" name="mobile_country_code">
//print your ajax response
</select>
```

But more standard way is to get a result from the ajax page is a json and create list box data in your page itself

Refer Examples
[Sample Document which describes the process](http://www.techsofttutorials.com/ajax-country-state-city-dropdown-using-phpmysql/)

Comment: You mean to say I have to remove the PHP code from the second dropdown?

Comment: that is not my issue which link you shared in the answer. that's output I am already getting it. My issue is if you select the INDIA from dropdown than in the second dropdown it will display the country phone code +91 but I also I need all the country code in the same drop down

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON array to pass the new options.
Modifying select options in html level is not recommended.
Here's the code.

```
$('#select_country').dropdown({
     onChange: function(val) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"process.php?key=country_mobilecode",
        method:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data:'country_id='+val,
        success:function(data){

    $('.p_code').empty();

    $.each(data.options, function (i, item) {
        $('.p_code').append($('<option>', { 
            value: item.value,
            text : item.text 
        }));
    });

        }
       });
     }
    });
```

Process.php

```
$country_sc=$conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['country_id']));
  $state_data="SELECT phonecode FROM `countries` WHERE sortname=?";
  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($state_data)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $country_sc);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($phonecode);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

$new_option[options][]=array('value'=>$phonecode,'text'=>$phonecode);
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

echo json_encode($new_option);
```

Comment: I think there is some issue with AJAX because I am not getting the output in the second dropdown.

Comment: can you try to alert the value and see if there's undefined variables?

Comment: I added the alert after success and I got [object Object] in the alert.

Comment: use developer tools to inspect the object. see if the value is correct or empty.

Comment: I recommend you to check your html markup and see if there's any unclosed tags. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: I checked in the network tab -> response. I am getting the country phone code. Like This time I select India and I got 91 in the response

Comment: $.each(data.options, function (i, item) {
console.log(item.value);}

Comment: any more help in this?